# Post-Update Git Hook Not Finding Directory

Tags: git, msysgit, githooks

I am setting up an environment where I can push changes done locally on my workstation to "Hub" repository (which is a remote) and then a post-update hook will automatically update my staging web site, which is the "Prime".  I'm doing this so that I can see my changes get automatically reflected in my staging site when I push to my remote hub.

This set up is based on [this](http://joemaller.com/990/a-web-focused-git-workflow/) article.  My server is Windows 2012 and I'm using MSysGit on both the server and my workstation (Windows 7).

Everything is working fine when I do everything manually -- push from my local repo to the hub and then manually fetch/merge into the prime.  My problem is when I try to have the fetch/merge be done by a post-update hook.

When I commit a change to my hub, the output I get is:

```
c:\Code4X\GIT\stage>git push stage master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 518 bytes, done.
Total 6 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote: **** Pulling changes into Live [Stage's post-update hook]
remote:
remote: hooks/post-update: line 12: cd: /c/websites/myproject.staging: No
such file or directory
To w:/stage.git
   ce1e2ea..93e11f4  master -> master
```

My post-update hook is:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo
echo "**** Pulling changes into Live [Stage's post-update hook]"
echo

cd /c/websites/myproject.staging || exit
unset GIT_DIR
git pull stage master

exec git update-server-info
```

I'm able to fire up a bash cmd shell and cd to the directory without problem, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

I've also tried:

- including git\cmd in my PATH
- enclosing the path I'm trying to cd to in quotes (")
- having my shebang point to #!/c/progra~1/git/bin/sh

Hopefully it's something obvious.  Any thoughts as to what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

I *just* got through doing something somewhat similar on one of my projects. It looks like you have the right idea.

Try using relative paths instead.

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
# You are now in the project root
cd ../project.prime
git pull stage master
```

I figured I'd let you know what I'm doing, as this may help you out. This script will force update the working copy every time the repo gets updated:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd ..
git checkout -f
```

Comment: I'll have to give that a shot.  I thought about relative paths, but I never tried it.  I'll let you know how it goes.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The article you're using as a reference appears to assume that the hub and prime live on the same host.  Perhaps you have those on separate hosts, thereby meaning the the post-update hook is running where there really is no /c/websites/myproject.staging (it executes on the remote receiving the push)?

Furthermore, while the author's advice to avoid pushing to a non-bare repository is generally valid, scripting a pull in this manner is roughly equivalent to doing so, so perhaps change that to chain the push to a remote on hub (that points to prime) within post-update?  That will allow it to work with hub and prime residing on separate hosts and remove the need navigate directories in the hook altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](http://debuggable.com/posts/git-tip-auto-update-working-tree-via-post-receive-hook:49551efe-6414-4e86-aec6-544f4834cda3): precede any git command run in post-hook with "env -i".   Thus:

```
cd /path/to/other/repo && env -i git pull
```

The reason, as detailed in the post, is that the post-hook command runs with the GIT_DIR environment variable set, so any git commands that are run look at your old repo, not the one you're in.  "env -i" is one way of unsetting that variable.